# Hibernate criteriaQuery, filter only subclass entitles

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Provide, there is the next hierarchy:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
Class A{
  String name;
}

Class B extends A{
  boolean isActive;
}
```

Then, I need to filter by several criterias, including `isActive`.

I decided to deal with `Specification`.
But faced one issue. When I am making filtration by `isActive = false`, I am getting all subClass entities with `isActive=false`. Totally ignoring parent class entities. My expected result is to get all entities from parent class, and filtered entities from suClass. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Specification for your case. I guess you want to get parents by child property. I suggest you to use `Boolean` class for boolean properties as it will distinguish `null` and `false` values. For selecting a child by class you can use JPQL `TYPE` operator. You can find an example here on how to do it :

Parent class :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Child 1 class :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Bar extends Foo {
    private Boolean active;
}
```

Child 2 class :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Qux extends Foo {
    private Boolean done;
}
```

Repository :

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    @Query("select f from Foo f where TYPE(f) = Bar and f.active = false")
    List<Foo> findByActive();
}
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTests {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Bar bar1 = new Bar();
        bar1.setActive(false);
        Foo foo1 = bar1;
        foo1.setName("foo1");
        fooRepository.save(foo1);

        Bar bar2 = new Bar();
        Foo foo2 = bar2;
        foo2.setName("foo2");
        fooRepository.save(foo2);

        Foo foo3 = new Qux();
        foo3.setName("foo3");
        fooRepository.save(foo3);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(fooRepository.findByActive());
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.